# Is the series convergent $x + x^{1+\frac{1}{2}}+x^{1+\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{3}}+\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$x + x^{1+\frac{1}{2}}+x^{1+\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{3}}+\cdots$$

I know that $u_n = \lim_{n \to \infty}   x^ {\sum_{i=1}^n(1/i)}$

I used root test and ratio test but it isn't working.

Comment: What about the nature of $x$ ?

Comment: @Khosrotash nothing said, I assume it is >0

Comment: The $n$th term is closely related to $x^{\ln n}=n^{\ln x}$, so may be we need something like $0\le x<1/e$?

Comment: ... and I just became a fortune teller. I foresee a bunch of sophomores battling with this later this fall :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yeah probably xD

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

The $n$th term is

$$x^{1+{1\over2}+\cdots+{1\over n}}\approx x^{\log n}=e^{\log x\log n}=n^{\log x}$$

so you would expect the series to converge when $\log x\lt-1$ and diverge when $\log x\gt-1$.  It's a little unclear what happens when $\log x=-1$ (since $n^{\log x}$ is only an approximation).

Comment: when $logx=-1$ won't the series diverge as it will be $n^{-1}$?

Comment: The approximation with $x^{\log n}$ is off by a factor that is bounded from above and below by a power of $x$, i.e. a constant. I don't know what happens with $x=1/e$ either :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Exactly the same works for $1/e$ since the harmonic series diverges.

Answer (score 2):

Write $H_n=1+\frac{1}{2}+\dots+\frac{1}{n}$. [It can be shown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) that $\ln n<H_n\leq (\ln n)+1$. For $x\geq 1$ the series clearly diverges, so assume $x<1$. Then
$$xn^{\log x}=xe^{\log x\log n}=x^{(\log n)+1}>x^{H_n}>x^{\log n}=e^{\log x\log n}=n^{\log x}.$$
Therefore we can compare with the [$p$-series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#p-series), $p=\log x$. It converges iff $\log x=p<-1$, i.e. $x<\frac{1}{e}$.

(note: $x>0$ is assumed throughout. If $x<0$ elements of the series are not well-defined, $x=0$ is trivial.)

Comment: At first I mis-interpeted $\ln n +1$ as $\ln (n+1)$ so my edit was to add brackets in case someone else is as dumb as I am :)...............+1

Comment: $H_n=\gamma+\ln (\frac {1}{ 2 }n)+O(n^{-2})$ where $\gamma = 0.5771...$ is Euler's Constant. So when $x=e^{-1}$ we have $x^{H_n}=\frac {\exp (-\gamma)}{n+\frac 1 2}$ $ \exp (O(n^{-2}))$, which is greater than $\exp (-\gamma)/(2n)$ for all but finitely many $n.$ So the series diverges when $x=e^{-1}$

Comment: My second edit was to change $x^{(\ln n)+1}=x^{H_n}$ to $x^{(\ln n)+1}>x^{H_n}$ which I am sure was just a typo..... ERROR (of mine): In my comment on the case $x=e^{-1}$ the first formula should be $H_n=\gamma +\ln (\frac {1}{2}+n)+O(n^{-2}).$

Comment: Thank you for your edits!

Comment: @Wojowu hey please explain how $ x.n^{\log n}=x.e^{(\log x).(\log n)}$ when x<1.

Comment: @SaurabhRana $n=e^{\log n}$, so $n^{\log x}=(e^{\log n})^{\log x}=e^{\log n\log x}$.

Answer (score 0):

It's $\enspace \ln n +\gamma <H_n<\ln(n+1) + \gamma\enspace$ for $\,n\in\mathbb{N}\,$ .

We get $\enspace\displaystyle\frac{1}{e^\gamma(n+1)}<\frac{1}{e^{H_n}}<\frac{1}{e^\gamma n}\enspace$ and therefore $$ e^{-\gamma x}(\zeta(x)-1)< \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty e^{-xH_n} <e^{-\gamma x}\zeta(x)$$

which is valid for $\,x>1\,$ .

It follows that $\enspace\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty x^{H_n}\enspace$ exists for $\enspace\displaystyle 0\leq x<\frac{1}{e}\,$ .